# Limit of goniometric function without l'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying figure this out without l'Hospital's rule. But I don't know how should I start. Any hint, please?

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1-\sin x}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 }$$

Comment: Your equation makes no sense.  $\sin$ needs an argument, at the very least.

Comment: Why isn't this trivially $0$?  You have a constant in the denominator (which can be removed) and the numerator is clearly $0$.

Comment: answer in the book is 1/2. But I cannot solve it. Also in wolfram alpha..

Comment: Shouldn't be the $1$ in the denominator replaced by $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $t=\frac \pi2 - x,$ 
$$\lim_{x\to {\pi\over 2}} \frac {1-\sin x}{(\frac\pi2 -x)^2}=\lim_{t\to {0}} \frac {1-\cos t}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to {0}} \frac {2 \sin ^2(t/2)}{4(t/2)^2}={1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1-\sin x}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 }
=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1-\sin x}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 } \frac {1+\sin x}{1+\sin x}
=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1}{1+\sin x}\frac {\sin^2\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 } =\frac12$$

Comment: Is that right? we still have 0/0 in the second fraction

Comment: @LukášFrajt The second fraction is in the form $y\to 0 \quad \frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2} \to 1$.

Comment: @LukášFrajt The simpler way is note that $$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1-\sin x}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 }=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} \frac {1-\cos \left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)}{\left(\frac\pi2 -x\right)^2 }=\frac12$$ by standard limits.

Comment: Got it, thank you!